# меню 2 уровня в Битриксе

Tags: битрикс, cms, меню

не поулчается создать меню второго уровня,перерыл кучу форумов статей,делаю как говорят но ничего не выходит.
http://prntscr.com/js2ww2 вот тут создал обычное меню и под меню 
http://prntscr.com/js2xo2 сделал обычное меню и в настройках поставил вложенность 2 и назначил подменю
http://prntscr.com/js2yg3 в категории автопарк добавил новый пункт и подменю 
http://prntscr.com/js2z0n параметры меню

но при этом нету под меню в списке,не понимаю почему так 
http://prntscr.com/js306o 
и в коде подпункта тоже нету

Comment: Ты раскопировал шаблон .default? там нет такого функционала. используй шаблон horisontal multilevel или vertical multilevel

Comment: разобрался сам,но спасибо за ответ.